# Returning NSArray element

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

In MRC code returning NSArray element like this:

```
NSString* MyName()
{
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSHost currentHost] names]];
    return [names objectAtIndex:0];
}

void BullCrap()
{
    NSString *wouldItBeRetainedAutomatically = MyName();
}
```

`wouldItBeRetainedAutomatically` in `BullCrap()` scope? I am assuming I don't need to send `wouldItBeRetainedAutomatically` `retain` message to make sure it is still available after `names` in `MyName()` is deallocated? Or `names` wouldn't be deallocated until `BullCrap()` is done?

NOTE: I know I should use ARC, but i can't.

Comment: No use `autorelease` instead.

Comment: But why are you using MRC?

Comment: If you do that, you'll get yourself a leak. Actually, ```names``` would leak as it is now. ```autorelease``` the array and let the caller of the method retain the return value if it's needed.

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan `autorelease` and object that you are not creating? It would make sense if i owned the object by `alloc`, `new` or `copy`.

Comment: Also historical: "C", Assembly.

Comment: @NulledPointer I forgot. ```arrayWithArray:``` returns an autoreleased object. But still, retaining the array would make a leak.

Comment: You know Xcode has a helper to upgrade your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be completely sure the answer to this question is correct it would be necessary to see where `listOfNames` comes from. This will tell us what memory management contract has been made between the system framework and your calling code.

With that said, it is probably safe to say that the system framework has autoreleased the `NSArray` that was returned and stored in `listOfNames`.  So `listOfNames` will get released and disappear as soon as the autorelease pool is flushed.  You create the `name` array using `arrayWithArray` which will also return an autoreleased instance.

However, you are specifically asking about the memory management "state" of the first element of `listOfNames` (or `names`) that is returned by the `MyName` function.  This has almost certainly only been retained by the `listOfNames` array (and the `names` array).  (Again the caveat above still stands).  Given that `listOfNames` (and `names`) will get autoreleased shortly, the elements of the array will also get released.

Therefore, you should probably return the element from `MyName` with a call to `autorelease` and then retain `wouldItBeRetainedAutomatically` in `BullCrap` if you need it to stick around. There is nothing in the code that you've shown that would suggest it will be retained automatically for you.

On a side note, the `names` array that you create is unnecessary in the example you give.  The same could be achieved as follows:

```
NSString* MyName()
{
    //listOfNames is returned by SystemFramework API
    return [listOfNames objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Using the intermediate `names` array simply confuses the matter.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it looks like you shouldn't do anything, simply because you say `listOfNames` is returned by a system API and this method is (in a very contrived way) adding it to and then removing it from an array which will be destroyed. So, the array temporarily retains the `listOfNames` but doesn't really change anything and the `listOfNames` is (depending on how it was really created) already auto released.

Obviously there's a massive caveat on where `listOfNames` actually comes from...